# Comparing object in Java

Tags: java

Here is my application

```
public class testwithmain {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Money m12CHF = new Money(12,"CHF"); 
    System.out.println(m12CHF.amount());

    Money m14CHF = new Money(14,"CHF");
    System.out.println(m14CHF.amount());

    Money expected = new Money(26,"CHF");
    System.out.println("expected "+expected.amount()+expected.currency());

    Money result = m12CHF.add(m14CHF); 

    System.out.println("result "+result.amount()+result.currency());

    System.out.println(expected.equals(result));
}

}
//-------------------------
public class Money { 
    private int fAmount; 
    private String fCurrency; 
    public Money(int amount, String currency) {
        fAmount = amount; 
        fCurrency = currency;
    } 
    public int amount() {return fAmount;} 
    public String currency() {return fCurrency;} 
    public Money add(Money m) {
        return new Money(amount() + m.amount(), currency());
    } 
}
```

The result is:

```
12
14
expected 26CHF
result 26CHF
false
```

Please, why i have false ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is this ```Money``` class?

Comment: You probably need to `override` the `equals` method in your `Money` class I'm guessing and define what equality means for them.

Comment: public class Money 
{
private int fAmount;
private String fCurrency;

public Money(int amount, String currency) 
{fAmount = amount;
fCurrency = currency;}

public int amount() {return fAmount;}

public String currency() {return fCurrency;}


public Money add(Money m) 
{return new Money(amount() + m.amount(), currency());}
}

Comment: Edit the post with that information, not as a comment.

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: .equals() compares hash code of objects since both are created with new operator both will be allocated with different memory. As @Nexevis suggested you can override equals(). Note if you are overriding equals() you must override hashCode() also

Comment: Be careful with the name of the method and their purpose. `add` should better change the current object `this` and a method named `plus` whould return a new one

Comment: @user1543915, Your code allows adding `14 USD` to `1 CHF`. And the result will be 15 CHF. Do you think this is right?

Comment: 12,"CHF" not 1 CHF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Money` class lacks an implementation of `equals` method, which is required in order for Java to know that the object representing the result of `m12CHF.add(m14CHF)` and the `new Money(26,"CHF")` represent the same thing, even though the two are distinct Java objects.

The code inside `equals` should follow this general template:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    if (o == this) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    if (!(o instanceof Money)) { 
        return false; 
    }
    Money other = (Money) o; 
    ... // Your code goes here
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(fAmount, fCurrency);
}
```

Your implementation needs to compare `fAmount` and `fCurrency` of your object to the values in `other.fAmount` and `other.fCurrency`. Use `equals` for comparison of `String` objects; numbers can be compared with `==` operators.

Answer (score 0):

As Nexevis said you need to override the equals method (which is inherited from the object class)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
   if(obj instanceof Money){
     Money other = (Money)obj;
     //now you define when two intance object of Money are equal...
   }
   //...
}
```

**Why is this necessary?**
Because the current equals that you are using it is the equals from the Object class. Object's equals method defines that two objects are the same when they have the same reference

Comment: Whenever you override equals, you also have to override hashCode.